# How to start gulp task from other gulp task after gulp.start is deprecated in gulp V4?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I need to create gulp task called 'watch' to watch changes in index.html file and to start other gulp task called 'html' when changes are made in index.html. According to tutorial which I am following this should be done like this:

```
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    watch('app/index.html', function() {
        gulp.start('html');
    });
});
```

But it returns me error messages because gulp.start is deprecated in gulp v4. I tried several solutions using series and parallel methods, but to be honest I not understand that solutions at all and didn't get any results using this. Can someone show me how to do it on my simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Gulp tasks are now simple functions. There is no need to define a task via `gulp.task()`, you can simply define the function:

```
function html(cb) {
    // Do something
    cb()
}
```

Now the reference to the function `html` can be used as a task:

```
function watch() {
    return gulp.watch('app/index.html', html)
}
```

Please note, that the tasks defined as simple functions are considered *private* tasks, they cannot be called via `gulp <task>`. For this to work, you need to make them *public* by exporting them:

```
exports.html = html
exports.watch = watch
```

So, for your specific use case, you won't need `series` and `parallel`. However, you can pass the tasks (function references) to them in the same way to create other tasks:

```
exports.rebuild = gulp.series(clean, build)
```